# constexpr bug, std::is_same with multiple-inheritance

Tags: c++11, constexpr, type-traits

Compiling with VS2015:

```
template <typename Owner, typename C, typename R, typename... Args>
constexpr bool FunctionBelongsTo(R(C::*)(Args...) const)
{
  return std::is_same<C, Owner>::value;
}

class C
{
public:
  int x;
};
class D
{
public:
  int y;
};
class M : public C, public D
{
public:
  void f() const {}
};

static_assert(FunctionBelongsTo<M>(&M::f) != true, "TRUE");
```

The `constexpr` function gives a weird error:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
```

This `std::is_same` expression is most certainly constant.

The strange thing is, this error seems to be invoked in this very specific case where `M` is multiply inherited. Remove either of the base classes from `M` and it compiles just fine (ie, it emits the `static_assert`, as expected), but when `M` is multiply inherited like this, it decides the expression is not constant.

... what gives? Rookie error?

Comment: Your code is legitimate, this malignancy is attributed to visual studio since a lot of type trait staff is until now only partially supported.

Comment: both gcc and clang compile the code

Comment: I think what is messing VS is the method pointer. It doesn't evaluate it as a compile time constant.

Comment: @bolov obviously, but as I say, it does if you remove one of the base classes from the multiply inherited class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2015 Udpate 2 RC (CL version 19.00.23824.1) seems to fix this. You can also verify with a slightly older version at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/, so I'd hope it stays fixed when the update goes RTM.

Comment: The latest Update 3 still not fixed the issue.

Comment: @sniel I don't have Update 3 installed at the moment, but in VS "15" Preview 4 I get the expected `main.cpp(25): error C2338: TRUE`, same on the webcompiler.